# How to force card width in Bootstrap-vue?

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-vue

How do i set specific width to my cards and make it responsive. For now this codes puts all my items horizontally even on smaller devices, making the width of the card to shrink. but when i chose to display items vertically the width style works. How do i set the specific width to make it responsive and shift down to another row?

```
        <b-card
          v-for="project in projects"
          :key="project.id"
          :title="project.name"
          :img-src="project.image"
          tag="article"
          img-top
          class="font-1"
          style="width: 25rem"
        >
          <b-card-text>
            {{ project.description }}
          </b-card-text>

          <b-button size="sm" :href="project.live" variant="primary"
            >live</b-button
          >
          <b-button size="sm" :href="project.code" variant="primary"
            >code</b-button
          >
        </b-card>
      </b-card-group>
```

Comment: is using `max-width` solve your problem ?

Comment: @FarazA. It didn't. card group causes the card to lose width when items exceed row

Answer (score 1):

Thanks i've fixed it. Turns out b-card-group default style is not responsive. Replace that with a div row to style the card width for multiple items